# ListFragment doesn't re-display data when calling it from FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-listfragment, fragmentstatepageradapter

Here's my UI hierarchy:

Main Fragment -> Fragment with ActionBar.TabListener -> Fragment with FragmentStatePagerAdapter -> ListFragment

The issue is that the ListFragment does display the first time I go into the tab of the ListFragment, but it does not display the second time (so going to tab 2 displays it, but then going to tab 1 and then tab 2 it doesn't display itself. The ListFragment is in tab 2).

This layout works fine if I remove the FragmentStatePagerAdapter, but now my project requires pages, so I needed to add the FragmentStatePagerAdapter to make the paging work.

However, at this point I dont really know what the problem is. I dont know if the issue is in the FragmentStatePagerAdapter, the ListFragment or if the phone just for some reason looses the data of the ListFragment.
I do know that getItem in FragmentStatePagerAdapter does not get called again when switching tabs.

Here's my code for the TrendsPagerHolder and FragmentStatePagerAdapter (as inner class):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class TrendsPagerHolder extends Fragment
{
private ArrayList<String>testArray = new ArrayList<String>();
private Context context;
private SharedPreferences preferences;
private Bundle applicationStatus;

// The number of pages to display
private static final int NUM_PAGES = 3;

private ViewPager pager;

//The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget
private PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{       
    context = inflater.getContext();
    applicationStatus = savedInstanceState;
    View rootView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.trends_screen_slider, container, false);

    System.out.println("in TrendsPagerHolder onCreateView");

    pager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.trends_pager);   
    pagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());   
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    pager.setCurrentItem(0);

    return rootView;
}

public class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{       
    TrendsLV[] arrayOfTrendsFragments;

    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager)
    {

        super(fragmentManager);

        testArray.add("One");
        testArray.add("Two");
        testArray.add("Three");

        arrayOfTrendsFragments = new TrendsLV[NUM_PAGES];
        arrayOfTrendsFragments[0] = new TrendsLV(testArray, 0);
        arrayOfTrendsFragments[1] = new TrendsLV(testArray, 1);
        arrayOfTrendsFragments[2] = new TrendsLV(testArray, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) 
    {                       
        System.out.println("in getItem. Position = " + position);
        return arrayOfTrendsFragments[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }   
}
}
```

Here's the code for my ListFragment:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.AsyncTask.Status;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class TrendsLV extends ListFragment
{
private Context context;
private ArrayList<String>testArray;
private Bundle applicationStatus;
private int pageIndex;

public TrendsLV(ArrayList<String> test, int index)
{
    testArray = test;
    pageIndex = index;
}

public TrendsLV()
{
    // required
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{       
    context = inflater.getContext();
    applicationStatus = savedInstanceState;

    System.out.println("in TrendsLV onCreateView");

    if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {                               
            if (testArray != null)
            {
                TrendsListAdapter adapter = new TrendsListAdapter(context, testArray, pageIndex);
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }

    }
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
}//end class TrendsLV
```

And here's the code for the Adapter that is called from the ListFragment:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class TrendsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
    {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String>testArray;
    private int pageIndex;

    public TrendsListAdapter (Context c, ArrayList<String> test, int index)
    {
        super(c, R.layout.trends_row, test);
        context = c;
        testArray = test;

        pageIndex = index;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trends_row, parent, false);
        TextView label_totalArea = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.trends_labelTotalArea);
        label_totalArea.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.stringTotalArea));

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need additional information to solve this issue.
I am testing it on a device using Android 4.4.4.

Thank you.

Comment: Nobody after a day?? :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are inflating `Fragment` inside `Fragment` you should use `getChildFragmentManager()` instaed of `getFragmentManager()`.

Here is the doc : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()

```
 public class TrendsPagerHolder extends Fragment
{
private ArrayList<String>testArray = new ArrayList<String>();
private Context context;
private SharedPreferences preferences;
private Bundle applicationStatus;

// The number of pages to display
private static final int NUM_PAGES = 3;

private ViewPager pager;

//The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget
private PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{       
    context = inflater.getContext();
    applicationStatus = savedInstanceState;
    View rootView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.trends_screen_slider, container, false);

    System.out.println("in TrendsPagerHolder onCreateView");

    pager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.trends_pager);   
    pagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());   
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    pager.setCurrentItem(0);

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: In which class would this modifications need to be made?

Comment: @TooManyEduardos TrendsPagerHolder. Edited the answer.

Comment: I get this error: "Call requires API level 17 (current min is 15): android.app.Fragment#getChildFragmentManager"

Is there a way to use this with the existing level 15 I have already deployed my app as?

Comment: Also, even changing to getChildFragmentManager(), the issue continues after I rotate the phone

Comment: Use the `Fragment` class from v4 support librray to support lower android versions.

Comment: And about roation issue, are you loading the data only if the orientaion is portrait? Check the condition inside `TrendsLV` class -  `if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)`

Comment: Yeah I have the data saved on rotation. The data shows up on landscape but when you come back to portrait the table doesn't display pages 1 and 2 of the viewpager. Page 3 shows up and if you "scroll" back to pages 1 and 2, pages 1 shows up. Page 2 never shows up after rotation. It's super weird and extremely annoying

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create the instance of ListFragment and use that instance in FragmentStatePagerAdapter.. some thing like this..

In Your **TrendsLV** class , remove the constructor and add below method to create the instance of fragment..

```
public static TrendsLV newInstance(ArrayList<String> test, int index) {
    TrendsLV fragment = new TrendsLV();
     testArray = test;
     pageIndex = index;
    return fragment;
}
```

Then update your ScreenSlidePagerAdapter as follow..

```
    public class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{       
    TrendsLV[] arrayOfTrendsFragments;

    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager)
    {

        super(fragmentManager);

        testArray.add("One");
        testArray.add("Two");
        testArray.add("Three");

        arrayOfTrendsFragments = new TrendsLV[NUM_PAGES];
        arrayOfTrendsFragments[0] = TrendsLV.newInstance(testArray, 0);
        arrayOfTrendsFragments[1] = TrendsLV.newInstance(testArray, 1)
        arrayOfTrendsFragments[2] = TrendsLV.newInstance(testArray, 2)
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) 
    {                       
        System.out.println("in getItem. Position = " + position);
        return arrayOfTrendsFragments[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }   
}
```

or instead of creating the array of fragments.. you can replace the in getItem() method like this..

```
   public class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{       


    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager)
    {

        super(fragmentManager);

        testArray.add("One");
        testArray.add("Two");
        testArray.add("Three");

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) 
    {                       
        System.out.println("in getItem. Position = " + position);

        Fragment instanceFragment = null;

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            instanceFragment =TrendsLV.newInstance(testArray, 0);;

            break;
        case 1:
            instanceFragment =TrendsLV.newInstance(testArray, 1);;

            break;
        case 2:
            instanceFragment =TrendsLV.newInstance(testArray, 2);;

            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return instanceFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }   
}
```

I don't know what is the use of `testArray` so i haven't made any changes for it.

Hope it helps..!! :)

Comment: so your suggestion is to remove the onCreate methods and anything related to that, is that correct?

Comment: If i remove the adapter from TrendsLV, how am I going to be calling the content of the list view?

Comment: no my suggestion is to remove the constructor of trendsLV and add newInstance() method. by mistake i wrote adapter instead of constructor.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work either. After rotating the device the TrendsLV does not display